# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list

Tags: r

I work in RStudio and I found a similar question but the answers didn't quite fit my needs or I just didn't properly understood them. I am working with 3 networks made in Excel, saved in CSV comma delimited, I'm using "**igraph**" and "**statnet**" and I keep getting the message "**Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list.**" for the "test_01" object from the code below.
The answers that I found were saying that it may be because there are functions with the same name in the packages I'm using but this doesn't seem to be the case. It's my first time posting and I am still a beginner at using RStudio so I'm still a bit confused about some things. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
money.network <- network(as.matrix.money, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
money.network
money.network%v%"age" <- friends$age
money.network%v%"sex" <- friends$sex

test_01 <- netlogit(money.network, list(trust.graph, like.graph),
                     intercept = TRUE, mode = "digraph",
                     diag = FALSE, nullhyp = c("qap"),
                     test.statistic = c("z-value"),
                     tol = 1e-7, reps = 1000)
```